# What particles carry various forms of energy?

Tags: particle-physics, energy

If I didn't get this wrong, light or heat energy consists of photons and they in turn effect electrons' behavior and thus responsible for chemical and electrical energy. What kind of similar particle like photons are kinetic energy of objects?

What about other forms of energy, like potential energy especially in springs (gravity remains tricky I understand)? I'm not specialized in physics so please simplify your answer as much as you can...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kinetic energy need not be carried by any special carrier particle. Kinetic energy is inherent in any moving body or particle.

If you look closely at the conservation of energy/work energy theorem, all you get is that $$\Delta\left(\frac12mv^2\right)=\int \vec F\cdot d\vec x$$

The left hand side is (change in) "kinetic energy". The right hand side is change is potential energy. Calling both of these terms as energy is a convenience that makes it cleaner to state the conservation of energy in terms of one quantity ($E$).

Fundamentally, kinetic energy is inherent in any moving body. On the other hand, forces are caused by exchange of gauge bosons, so *potential* energy is in the end "mediated" by various particles (like the photon). I wouldn't go so afar as to say that it is "carried" by particles, though. The forces are mediated by the particles; but the potential energy is still a property of the system.

Springs work on the basis of electromagnetic energy. (All forces like the stress reaction force, forces between materials when you push two together, etc come from electrostatic repulsion between electrons in atoms.)

---

Photons carrying heat energy and photons mediating the EM force are very, very different.

When you transfer heat, the kinetic (vibrational) energy of the body is manifested in the form of an emitted photon. All that energy is now the kinetic energy of the photon. The photon finally bumps into some other material and is absorbed, turning into electrostatic or kinetic energy. All photons here are real photons.

On the other hand, the electromagnetic force (and the other fundamental forces) is generally mediated by *virtual particles* (photons). These live on borrowed energy, and don't contribute to the potential energy of an interaction. The energy of the interaction is part of the system, not really tied to any individual entity.

Comment: Potential energy is a property of a *system*, not of the individual bodies that comprise it. This is a common confusion because you often start out talking about a single body moving in some fixed external field - the gravitational field of the Earth for instance. But once you have many bodies dynamically interacting with each other it is, more often than not, nonsense to ascribe potential energies to the individual bodies, since the thing that really matters is the *total* potential energy and that depends on the position of everything.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: Oops. I meant to say system there :s Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Yes but if you add thermal energy (heat) to an object that means that you added photons. And forms of energy transform to each other when for instance, heat energy transforms to kinetic energy some of that heat energy is reduced thus photons are reduced. What do they turn into? Shouldn't all forms of energies have carriers? If not then how some and not the others?

Comment: @Jim: You added photons, which were absorbed by the material making it jiggle. The photons are gone.

Like it's mentioned above, _none_ of the forms of energy have carriers. Heat energy is just a fancy word for kinetic energy. When heat is transferred via radiation, it is the KE of a photon. When heat is transferred via conduction/convection it is vibrational KE of molecules. The only forms of energy that have carriers are those which are fancy names for kinetic energy.

Also: Electromagnetic energy is not "carried" by photons. The force is. The energy is a property of the system.

Comment: @Manishearth When I said photons are heat energy; was because I know that -and correct me if im wrong- they are photons with low frequency (IR waves) capable of making molecules to vibrate and that this frequency keeps rising in the electromagnetic spectrum all the way through visible light up to gamma rays. So what your saying is that photons or similar carriers (i.e. gravitons) are not carriers of energy they have energies themselves. My knowledge doesn't extend to the 4 interactions, just the mainly :)

Comment: It's a strange thing how terms as simple as Energy (joule) and force (newton), we learned about in early days of school remain vague. I would ask you what is the difference between force and energy is, but that would be too dull specially to people like you..

Comment: @Jim: IR waves have the capacity to excite atoms because they fall in the correct energy range (bit of quantum mechanics here). They are effective media of "transfer of heat by radiation". But the energy in them is nothing but the inherent kinetic energy of the photon. And when they are absorbed by atoms, all they impart is kinetic energy. "heat" is just something we call it, it's all just kinetic energy. Yes, the force carriers have some energy. However, the potential energy of an interaction is not all stuffed within the force carriers.

Comment: @Jim: Force is rate of change of momentum. Energy doesn't really have a direct interpretation. (See http://www.quora.com/Physics/What-exactly-is-energy/answer/Manish-Goregaokar). You can talk of energy in terms of work, but then you have to define _that_.

Comment: @Manishearth I would sum up the following from what you're saying: kinetic and potential energy is energy in its simplest form. When photons have different types of kinetic energy they form EM FORCES (including light). Force carriers are FORCE carries which happen to carry kinetic energy in space on a subatomic level. Funny to know that when force is a fundamental of energy (Work=F.S). Kinetic energy of an object is all of its molecules moving together in the same direction. Quite interesting kinetic energy doesnt account for someTHING or particle on the contrary of all other things in nature.

Comment: @Jim: Force carriers carry _some_ kinetic energy. In fact, this is "borrowed" energy; and it is "given back" by another force carrier. (so the force carrier mechanism holds no energy of its own). The photons which "carry force" are "virtual" (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle). Energy _transfer_, on the other hand, is done via a medium consisting of real particles, which could be anything (heat transfer by radiation is via real photons).

Comment: Well, maybe I should talk about "mechanical" energy instead, which contains rotational KE, translational KE, and vibrational KE. All three are kinetic energy, but when talking about objects, KE isn't the best term.

Comment: KE is just a mathematical manipulation of velocity, really, so there need not be something corresponding to it. Force is a fundamental of energy, but that doesn't mean that force carriers hold the energy. Potential energy is a quality of a _system_, not individual particles in a system.

Comment: "Energy transfer, on the other hand, is done via a medium consisting of real particles, which could be anything" By medium do you mean non vacuum?

Comment: "KE is just a mathematical manipulation of velocity" so can I translate this that energy is basically motion?

Comment: @JimArnold: Well, yeah. If you have two isolated systems, the only way to transfer energy is by chucking particles over the fence. Usually it's heat in the form of photons.

Comment: @JimArnold: "energy is motion" no, _kinetic_ energy is _related_ to motion.  Don't overanalyse things. Energy is a mathematical quantity, constructed for convenience. (Not exactly, though, later on you do learn that it is special in a way)

Comment: "Potential energy is a quality of a system, not individual particles in a system" which can be translated that potential energy defines the tendency of objects create MOTION as well, due to the relation in position between two objects whether outwards or inwards? Please forgive my need to press on details :D I have to put things in place in order to go further and read about interactions..

Comment: @JimArnold: Yeah, PE is the tendency of objects to create motion. In a way. I don't see what you mean by outwards/inwards

Comment: Sorry my bad I thought of something else (like charges).. :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, which clarified things greatly. I hope I didn't trouble you with my too many questions..

Comment: @JimArnold: no prob. I'll try to crystallize the important points of this discussion into the answer later. (btw, you can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the green tick next to it).

Answer (score 0):

All particles gravitate, so they carry gravitational potential energy. (Strictly speaking energy isn't always well-defined in general relativity, but you were asking for an answer low in technical details. Strictly speaking, one should better speak about the stress-energy densitites). They also carry energy associated to all other interactions that they engage in (eg electromagnetic, strong, weak). If they have a mass, that mass has an energy equivalent. So let me see. I guess the only particle that, according to this nomenclature, might get away with "carrying" only one type of energy is the graviton because it neither has a mass nor takes part in any other interaction but gravity. But then, we don't know if gravitons really exist. So leaving out the graviton, I think the answer to your question is: all particles do.

Comment: But photons as far as I can tell, doesn't have rest mass. All particles do what please explain further?